# How can I zip a file not a folder/directory in Python

Tags: python, zip, shutil

I am trying to zip a file and not a folder or a directory.

Here is how I thought of doing it:

```
from shutil import make_archive

make_archive("name_of_zip", "zip", "image.png")
```

*I know I can use* *`ZipFile`* *but I have heard that it is not so reliable.*

But I get an error because I cant zip a file and I can only zip a directory.

```
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'image.png'
```

Is there a way to do this in Python or would I have to use subprocess and run a like this :

```
$ zip zip_with_image.zip image.png
  adding: requirements.txt (stored 0%)
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html). You can use the below code to zip the files.

```
$ python -m zipfile -c monty.zip spam.txt eggs.txt
```

Comment: But your solution would require me to use subporcess. I am trying to find a way to do it in fully Python and not use any bash commands

Comment: with ZipFile('spam.zip', 'w') as myzip:
    myzip.write('eggs.txt')

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `zipfile` module:

```
>>> from zipfile import ZipFile
>>> with ZipFile("mynew.zip","w") as myzip:
...  myzip.write('z.py')
...
```

Results in a local file called `mynew.zip` containing the single file `z.py`
If you require more files to be added to the zip, keep doing `myzip.write('filename')`, until you have finished.